# How do i get Flex to match a regex a maximum of once per word

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm new to flex and have been toying around with it a bit.
The task is trying to do now is find out how many of the following 18 strings:
    pVV pVV pppVVV pppV pppVVV ppV pVVV pV pppVV pV ppVVV ppVV pVVV
    ppVV ppVVV pVV pppVVV pppVVV
are matched at least once, in part or whole, by the flex regular expression:
             (ppp|VV)

I have the following code but it gives me the total number of matches and double counts certain strings. How would i change this code so that it only matches a word a maximum of once? Thanks in advance!

```
%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>  
    int matches = 0;
%}

%%      
(ppp|VV)    {   matches++; }
%%

int main()
{
    yylex();
    printf("%d\n", matches);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags in the hopes that your question will be seen by more people. Adding irrelevant tags is a good way to get irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is a tool for analyzing an input stream into tokens.

It is not a general purpose regular expression driver. If your task has nothing to do with splitting an input stream into individual tokens, you are probably using the wrong tool.

I think what you are trying to do here is to divide the input stream into tokens and then categorize the tokens. Flex can be used for that, but you need to be clear about what a token is. You also need to remember that the *entire input stream* needs to be handled; you can't just do a regex search in the input stream for something you're interested in. *Everything* -- even whitespace -- must be part of some token.

In this case, it seems plausible that your tokens consist of

- "words"
- everything else.

You don't, however, say what you consider a "word" to be. We could guess that a word is any sequence of non-whitespace characters, but you might have a more restricted definition. (Maybe you mean just letters and digits. Or even just letters. Or perhaps some punctuation is to be allowed).

Of the "words", you are interested in which ones *contain* the sequences `ppp` or `VV`. So that gives you three kind of tokens:

- everything which isn't a word
- "words" which contain `ppp` or `VV`
- any other "words".

Assuming that you really meant that a "word" is any sequence of non-whitespace characters, that categorization could be done with the following simple set of flex patterns:

```
[[:space:]]+                        ; /* Ignore whitespace */
[^[:space:]]*(ppp|VV)[^[:space:]]*  { matches++; }
[^[:space:]]+                       ; /* Ignore other words */
```

Note that the above is completely dependent on how you define a "word", which you haven't done (at least, not in your question). So it might only have a slight resemblance to your actual problem, but it should be easy to adapt.

For a complete description of the regular expression syntax, read the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). The syntax should be familiar, but it's not the same any regex library, and you will find most online regex tools do not understand Flex's syntax.